# asp.net mvc 2: set master page in WebFormViewEngine's FindView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewengine

I got a problem with a custom ViewEngine. I try to overrite the FindView method to set the master view without having to define it in each and every view page.

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterName))
    {
        masterName = this.MasterView;
    }
    return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
}
```

From the debuggers view everything looks fine: I don't set the property MasterPageFile on the view page, masterName comes in as an empty string, masterName gets set to this.MasterView (which gets set by initializing the view engine).

Trouble is: The browser displays "Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page." without the debugger showing up.

Does anyone know why or if this is even an expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it. To get it to work (at least in my case) one just has to remove the default view engine:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
```

And then add the new (custom) one:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AreaViewEngine(this.MasterView));
```

et voila, it works.

Comment: Yeah... maybe there's a way to change the priorities of viewengines or something like that, so that no clear would be necessary... who knows ;-)